# When registering a new account on my site this error pops up. Everything else works fine

Tags: php

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> **Severity:** Notice
> **Message:** Trying to get property of non-object
> **Filename:** models/Email_model.php
> **Line Number:** 187
>
> **Backtrace:**
>
> File: /public_html/application/models/Email_model.php Line: 187
> Function: _error_handler
> File: public_html/application/controllers/Home.php Line: 1409
> Function: send_code_sms
> File: /public_html/index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once

**Controller:**

```
if ($this->input->post('password1') == $this->input->post('password2')) {
    $password = $this->input->post('password1');
    $data['password'] = sha1($password);
    $this->db->insert('vendor', $data);
    $this->email_model->account_opening('vendor', $data['email'], $password);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    *$this->email_model->send_code_sms('vendor', $id);*
    echo 'done';
}
```

**Model:**

```
//email_verify
function send_code_sms($type,$id){        
    $code = $this->db->get_where($type,array($type.'_id' => $para2))->row()->sms_code;  
    *$phone = $this->db->get_where($type,array($type.'_id' => $para2))->row()->phone;*
    $text = translate('your_verification_code_is')." : ".$code;
    $this->do_sms($phone,$text);
}
```

**View:**

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

I am having this error on my site. I Sent an email to my developer to fix the errors causing my customers to be unable to register accounts but I have not received any replies in 5 days. The sms verification feature is not supposed to used yet because of no api. So the only thing supposed to be working is email verification. Whenever someone tries to register, the error above appears.
Need Help. Thanks

*(There is an asterisk to indicate the line with the error)*

Comment: Add exactly line number 187 of Email_Model.php

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?  The message is pretty clear, there's a line of code attempting to read a property on a variable which isn't set to an object.  So which attempt to do that is the one that's failing?

Comment: Whatever the value is on line 187, the variable is not an object. It could possibly be one of the following: `null`, `false`, `true`, `string`, and `array`

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` with the variable on line 187 in parenthesis.

Comment: @jeff A Victor Change $para2 to $id and try. $para2 is not define in function. However its pass as variable in query. I think I should be $id

Comment: @shafiq i tried that. but it did not work.

Comment: @McStuffins i have added asterisks to indicate line 187. how do fix the problem..

Comment: @jeff A Victor try replace 187 with following code and try.
$phone = '';
$phoneNumber = $this->db->get_where($type, array($type . '_id' => $para2))->row();
        if (isset($phoneNumber) && !empty($phoneNumber)) {
            $phone = $phoneNumber->phone;
        }